# Factory not keeping data when used in controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory House

'use strict';

```
myApp
.factory('House', [ '$http', '$location', '$rootScope', function($http, $location, $rootScope){

    var numberOfDoors;

    return {

        loadHouse: function(){
           numberOfDoors = 1;
        },

        numberOfDoors: numberOfDoors


    };
}]);
```

And I have a controller Owner

```
myApp
.controller('OwnerCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', 'House', function($rootScope, $scope, $location, House) {


    $scope.buildMe = function() {

        //use value from house
        var sayHelloToDoors = House.numberOfDoors;

    };
}]);
```

If I run a function `House.loadHouse()` in some other controller in order to set the variable `numberOfDoors` - I do set it, but when I switch to a page to reuse that number, I get a `undefined` message in `Owner` controller.

Why the value is cleared? It seems like another instance of House is transfered.
Could anybody help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you're assigning the value of private *numberOfDoors* to the field *numberOfDoors* in the factory.

```
// This following snippet ...

myApp.factory('house', function() {
  var numberOfDoors;

  return {
    numberOfDoors: numberOfDoors
  };
});

// ... will actually become

myApp.factory('house', function() {
  var numberOfDoors; // === undefined

  return {
    numberOfDoors: undefined
  };
});
```

Even if you would assign the private *numberOfDoors* an initial value, it would not behave the way you want it to.

```
myApp.factory('house', function() {
  var numberOfDoors = 123;

  return {
    loadHouse: function() {
      numberOfDoors = 1; // will change the private variable
                         // not the exposed object variable
    },
    numberOfDoors: numberOfDoors // will always be 123
  };
});
```

Easiest way to make this work is doing something like this:

```
myApp.factory('house', function() {

  return {
    reset: function() {
      this.numberOfDoors = 0;
    }, 
    numberOfDoors: 0
  };

});
```

You can play with in action at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SNpIBpSx0h2HIjjRkhVA?p=preview).

Edit:

To encapsulate the number of doors you could do something like this:

```
myApp.factory('house', function() {

  var _numberOfDoors = 0;

  return {
    reset: function() {
      _numberOfDoors = 0;
    }, 
    numberOfDoors: function(value) {

      if(value!==undefined) {
        _numberOfDoors = value;
      }

      return _numberOfDoors;
    }
  };

});
```

Now from your controller you can:

```
var count = house.numberOfDoors(); // Get the numberOfDoors
house.numberOfDoors(++count);      // Set the numberOfDoors
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such detailed answer and the plunker, you really made an effort. What I don't understand here is that why it wouldn't be possible to return a `private` variable but via `public` method. The thing is that I am doing such in my Authentication factory, and the currentUser variable stays visible, but here `numberOfDoors` doesn't :/

Comment: Actually you can return a private variable by a public method. But you have to define the function returning the variable to the object field and not the variable itself. I'll update the answer to clarify.

Comment: Oh and I'm guessing the currentUser variable you're referring to is an object type, not a value type. Doing something like `{ user: { name: 'john' } }` will expose a reference to the object `{ name: 'john' }`. So changes to the property `name` are reflected everywhere.

Comment: @Aleks I guess you're not hoping for a better answer.

Comment: @null you are guessing good :) I have used exactly that. The answer looks perfect. I will tru it tomorrow and I will let you know how did I go :) +1 now and a solved tomorrow ;)

Comment: I have marked it as solved. Thank you so much, you have explained it quite well and I use `_variable` now more often ;) when I need to ,and functions where I want. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change "numberOfDoors: numberOfDoors" to "numberOfDoors: function(){return numberOfDoors;}"

Please see this simple: (available in [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RaVW3nLYP632R47xsMrK?p=preview))

```
var service = (function(){
  var privateVar = 0;
  return{
    updateVar: function(val){
      privateVar = val;
    },
    getVar2: privateVar,
    getVar: function(){
      return privateVar;
    }

  }
})();

var instanceA = (function(){
  service.updateVar(1);
  alert(service.getVar());

})();


var instanceB = (function(){
  alert(service.getVar());
  alert(service.getVar2);

})();
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try both answers tomorrow as it quite late here. But I will return tomorrow